# How to rollback git project in github or bitbucket to previous version as in heroku using terminal commands?

Tags: git, heroku, github, version-control, bitbucket

I want to know how to rollback git project to previous version after commit. I experienced that heroku keeps activity log for web projects and has the capability of rolling back to previous version with simple options.Is this facility available for github or atlassian bitbucket ? Is there any commands for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Description

Yes, both services provide such utilities. There are a number of commands that you can execute to achieve a roll-back but they all depend on the way they treat *history*. Please see *some* git signatures below and their associated references for more information.

### Example

```
git revert <commit>
git rebase -i <HEAD~n>
git reset <commit>
git checkout <commit>
```

### Reference

[git-revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)
[git-rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)
[git-reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)
[git-checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

Comment: This helps me a lot. I'll check this out!

Comment: Happy i could help!

Answer (score 0):

This has already been asked and very well responded to here [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

You can either branch you current work or decided if you need to temporarily rollback commits or if you want to premanently remove commits.

Comment: Thank you . I'll check the answer you provided .